# Network manager applet doesn't show wired network connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, wired

I have the latest installs of `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome`. I installed Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04, then installed Cinnamon on top of that.

I have LAN network connection (can browse, etc.).

However, the network manager applet doesn't show the network connection as an icon, or when I click and open it. It's an empty list.

- If I `sudo service network-manager stop` the applet disappears.
- If I later `sudo service network-manager start` the applet appears again.

So presumably the applet knows about the `network-manager` service or the other way around perhaps.

How can I make the applet reflect the actual connected network(s)?

Comment: I'm having the same problem since yesterday. I remember doing system updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to edit /etc/network/interfaces and removed the line with my wired ethernet connection.

So long as the connection is listed in the interfaces file network-manager considers it as unmanaged (i.e. network-manager doesn't manage it), hence the nm-applet doesn't reflect the connection status.

I rebooted after editing and the nm-applet behaved!

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same problem after updating from 14.10 to 15.04.; the networks were still connecting, but the network manager didn't show any connections or interfaces.

What solved it for me was doing `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` as some packages were held back.

The network manager in Cinnamon looks good again.